# How to write the Lie algebra of multiplication on $\mathbb{R}$\ $\{0\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Context:

I have now made another attempt to understand the below resulting in a copy of $\mathbb{R}$ for the tangent space.  The attempt and reasoning are in the comments. Please go soft on me. I am trying. The question is below. Ignore the extended comments - I have now added some context and shown my attempt in the comments.

---

Question:

Multiplication on $\mathbb{R}$\ $\{0\}$ is a Lie group.

How is the Lie algebra of this Lie group constructed step by step?

I'm available to clarify the question further in the comments if it is not clear for any reason.

---

Silly things I said earlier left here because it has some context of where and why I asked the question ( Extended comments )

---

I can't possibly see why this question was downvoted. It is simple, clear, and straightforward. I even said I can clarify further in the comments. I just want to see it computed so I can check that I am not getting the same answer by chance and then I will apply it to the slightly more non-trivial group. In the last rendition of this question - now deleted, I asked the full question and tried to outline the steps I took to get to the answer but it did not work out as a good question so I have reduced the question to the form above. It is almost too basic for a mathematician (I'm learning) but I still sort of want to see a computation just once. There are plenty of definitions and statements in books, but I can't find the computation for something as basic as this.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138111/discussion-on-question-by-kevin-njokom-how-to-write-the-lie-algebra-of-multiplic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Lie group is in particular a differentiable manifold. The Lie algebra consists of the tangent space at the identity element, or else left-invariant vector fields (and vector fields consist of tangent vectors). Tangent vectors may be defined as equivalence classes of differentiable paths through a point, or else certain kinds of "derivations" of the algebra of smooth functions on the manifold. Complicated stuff.

But it's less complicated if you view the Lie group as a nice submanifold of Euclidean space, because then you can differentiate paths as vector functions and get tangent vectors in the sense we learn in multivariable calculus. In particular, matrix Lie groups have a much lower learning curve than the heavy differential geometry stuff (as in Stillwell's Naïve Lie Theory). "Most" Lie groups are linear (faithfully expressible by a matrix representation), but there are some that aren't.

In the 1D case, suppose $g(t)$ is any differentiable path in $\mathbb{R}^\times$ with $g(0)=1$ (note $1$ is the identity element of $\mathbb{R}^\times$); the corresponding tangent vector is $g'(0)$, which is just a scalar. Indeed, it can be any scalar $u$, by considering $g(t)=\exp(ut)$. (These exponential functions are the exponential functions in the sense of Lie theory too, and exhaust the one-parameter subgroups of this Lie group.) The scalars form a 1D space, $\mathbb{R}$ itself. In other words, every real scalar is a velocity vector of some path through the identity, no matter how big (just make the paths go faster through the identity!) or if negative (have the paths traverse the identity backwards!).

A good companion example would be the circle group $S^1$, viewed as the unit circle in the complex plane. (As with $\mathbb{R}^\times$, the group operation is multiplication.) Suppose $z(t)$ is any path in the unit circle with $z(0)=1$. Being on the unit circle means $|z|=1$, or equivalently $|z|^2=1$, which is the same as $z\overline{z}=1$. If we differentiate $z(t)\overline{z(t)}=1$ and then evaluate at $t=0$ we get $z'(0)+\overline{z'(0)}=0$, which forces the tangent vector $z'(0)$ to be pure imaginary. Indeed, it can be any imaginary number $i\omega$, considering $z(t)=\exp(i\omega t)$ (we can think of $\omega$ as the initial angular velocity!).

You can visualizing the tangent line to the unit circle at $z=1$ in the complex plane as a vertical line $1$ unit to the right of the imaginary axis, but these displacement vectors have $z=1$ as a basepoint and must be moved to have $z=0$ as a basepoint to be a vector space under addition.

Both $\mathbb{R}^\times=\mathrm{GL}_1\mathbb{R}$ and $S^1=\mathrm{U}(1)$ can be viewed as matrix groups by interpreting scalars as $1\times1$ matrices. In the case of matrix Lie groups, the lie bracket in the lie algebras are just the commutator bracket $[X,Y]=XY-YX$, where $XY$ is the usual matrix multiplication. (If you go into a general, abstract differential geometry setting, the definition of the lie bracket becomes are lot harder to understand.)